# Initial conditions after superposition theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

I have one circuit with one voltage of interest, $V_0$, that is dependent on 3 input voltages $U_i$ with $i=1,2,3$. I have broken down the circuit using the superposition theorem, which gave me 3 differential equations of this form:
$$\alpha_{i}\ddot{V_{0i}}+\beta_{i}\dot{V_{0i}}+\gamma_i{V_{0i}}=\delta_iU_i$$
$$i=1,2,3$$
Eq.1 is representative of the circuit with V1 alone, eq.2 with V2 alone, and eq.3 with V3 alone, but all of them express $V_0$, or rather $V_{0i}$.

However I need to set an initial condition on the total $V_0=\Sigma_i V_{0i}$ and breaking the circuit down using the superposition theorem gave me access only to the virtual $V_{0i}$, so how can I specify $V_0(t=0s)?$

### More information

Those equations are modelled using state space representation the following way:
$$\begin{bmatrix}\dot{V}_{01} \\ \ddot{V}_{01} \\ \dot{V}_{02} \\ \ddot{V}_{02} \\ \dot{V}_{03} \\ \ddot{V}_{03} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -\gamma_1/\alpha_1 & -\beta_1/\alpha_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -\gamma_2/\alpha_2 & -\beta_2/\alpha_2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\gamma_3/\alpha_3 & -\beta_3/\alpha_3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}{V}_{01} \\ \dot{V}_{01} \\ {V}_{02} \\ \dot{V}_{02} \\ {V}_{03} \\ \dot{V}_{03} \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \delta_1/\alpha_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \delta_2/\alpha_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \delta_3/\alpha_3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}U_1 \\ U_2 \\ U_3 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$ V_0 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}{V}_{01} \\ \dot{V}_{01} \\ {V}_{02} \\ \dot{V}_{02} \\ {V}_{03} \\ \dot{V}_{03} \end{bmatrix}$$
Typically initial conditions are done by setting the state vector $[V_{01} \dot{V_{01}} V_{02} \dot{V_{02}} V_{03} \dot{V_{03}}]$ to a certain value. All derivatives are zero initially however, I need to place an initial condition on the real, physical $V_0$; I don't know what the initial conditions on each virtual component $V_{0i}$ are.

Comment: Did I miss something, or do you have three totally independent equations to solve?

Comment: I would assume so. They are the result of the superposition theorem: one circuit with three voltage sources; eq.1 is representative of the circuit with V1 alone, eq.2 with V2 alone, and eq.3 with V3 alone, but all of them express V0 therefore V0 is the sum of the solutions to these equations. Updated my post.